# 'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'Type'

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am trying to make an event emitter for a peer to peer file transfer. But I am not sure how I can type this to get autocomplete for the event types and make sure the functions input are valid. I also want the correct type passed to the `on` function to be the type inferred when at the `Listener`. So if I do:

```
function onData(data: FileChunkData){}

transfer.on<FileStartData>('file:start', onData) // Should be invalid
```

I want this to be invalid because the args for data would be incompatible. `FileChunkData` is not assignable to `FileStartData`

Here is a super simplified version of what I have:

[Link to TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIghsOAeAKgPigXigbwLABQUxUokAXFAM7ABOAlgHYDmhJUYcIANgPZwATSviLsSwXpRoMWbMcQBmtXgFspdJq1HEAvlABkUFIR2FCZaADF63CAGEAFgFdGAa3iIssBMhHsAxs5ulACCtLRcAEJOCgoQtCZoZgQWUNa2AKKMAh5wXrlIfiQKNhBU9ABeEJSMTioARvGJyanpEADKiLTAufk%20hXKKpYxwKtXUGrIEOkkE5uDQADL0NBCM8agY2AAUAj6UKACUWBgAbrz0Ai0LUMur67RUm17tEMBId8BrG%20iz85C3FZfB5UACycDAXiKxAA2gByEq2cg0ODdOEAXUon2%20jyQbU6qJ6Plm7HhiOqgRcrgxWKBOKebUcVNyJJIZNK5DWAhpgPu8QZpSyOWJJigyX83DgVCoaVKKAijCocVouEGUG4dJBtL5j3BYGSAV4iroTn8Elo22O0LEwAcKwAdBqdTLsNb5LCERyUWjMVB1gB3KCvYCWgA0avdUHZSK5PIDQbeYYj7ujFKC1N98eDSe0YlMufz7DVRs223GrggIF4Cl5wP5etDUAUjG1ddom0ObuI9AU21tDqdbaoMIg6M7yeI-aojs1-JH6PtggE22bhwnejV%20fzhH8RpopAVSviXnjbXlcEVystLUPyvtJfxXSJiDQ209SO9wDhjd2%201wOmOTAMBwACoAAejAow7RlKgHF4JxuAEKBGigC8oCYU44A1JCFBcM16CNIA)

```
type Data<T> = {
    type: string
    payload: {
        to: string
        from: string
    } & T
}

type FileChunkData = Data<{
    chunk: ArrayBuffer
}>

type FileEndData = Data<{
    filesize: number
}>

type FileStartData = Data<{
    filename: string
}>

type Listener<T> = (data: T) => void

type Listeners<T> = Set<Listener<T>>

type ListenersMap = {
    ['file:start']: Listeners<FileStartData>
    ['file:chunk']: Listeners<FileChunkData>
    ['file:end']: Listeners<FileEndData>
} 

class FileTransfer {
    listeners: ListenersMap

    constructor() {
        this.listeners = {
            ['file:start']: new Set(),
            ['file:end']: new Set(),
            ['file:chunk']: new Set(),
        }
    }
    
    on<T>(e: keyof ListenersMap, fn: Listener<T>){
       if(this.listeners[e]){
        this.listeners[e].add(fn)
       } 
    }
}

const transfer = new FileTransfer()

transfer.on<FileStartData>('file:start', (data: {}) => {}) // This should be an invalid function
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Argument of type 'Listener<T>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Listener<FileStartData> & Listener<FileChunkData> & Listener<FileEndData>'.
  Type 'Listener<T>' is not assignable to type 'Listener<FileStartData>'.
    Type 'FileStartData' is not assignable to type 'T'.
      'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'FileStartData'.(2345)
```

How would I go about typing this so I can get good autocomplete options for the events and also make sure that the functions input into the event emitter are valid?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple reasons why TS is not complaining about the last line;

First, it expects a `Listener<T>` which is nothing more than a function that can get arguments of any type and it does not have to return anything so almost any function is compatible:

```
type Listener<T> = (data: T) => void
```

So if you want to restrict the arguments to specific types and benefit autocompletion you should name acceptable types, maybe you meant to have something this:

```
type Listener<T> = (data: FileStartData | FileChunkData | FileEndData) => void
```

Second, your function `(data: {}) => {}` is valid since when you have an empty object (`{}`) as an input argument you imply that you are using an `object` but don't need any of the props that you could use (props in `FileStartData`, `FileChunkData`, or `FileEndData`, so it seems fine to TS and you're not violating any rules.

And also as the return value TS expects no specific value (`void`) so you can return anything.

But it will complain if for example someone try to use something like this:

```
transfer.on('file:start', (data: string) => {}) // This should be an invalid function
```

Here's the edited [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIghsOAeAKgPigXigbwLABQUxUokAXFAM7ABOAlgHYDmhJUYcIANgPZwATSviLsSwXpRoMWbMcQBmtXgFspdJq1HEAvlABkUFIR2FCZaADF63CAGEAFgFdGAa3iIssBMhHsAxs5ulACCtLRcAEJOCgoQtCZoZgQWUNa2AKKMAh5wXrlIfiQKNhBU9ABeEJSMTioARvGJyanpEADKiLTAufk%20hXKKpYxwKtXUGrIEOkkE5uDQADL0NBCM8agY2AAUAj6UbZ1w3b0APmmlji7uPlDnbVk5PgCUWBgAbrz0Ai0LUMurda0KibLztCDAJAA4BrDboWbzSD-FYwoFUACycDAXiKxAA2gByEq2cg0Y7AAkAXUo0NhwKQhy6PR8s3YhOJ1UC1ypNJRdJBbSublyrJI7NK5DWAh5yMB8QFpUeIpMUGS-m4cCoVAuthQEUYVDitFwgyg3D5aN5cuBmLAyQCvANdCc-gktG2r1xYmADhWADpzdbtdgvfJ8USJWTujL1gB3KDg4AegA0prDUHFJKlMYg8cTKbTYcznKCrhzeYhBe0YlM1dr7FNjs223GrggIF4CllqPltuTUAUjCtPdom2eoeI9AU2x9-sDI6oeIglPHheIs6oAYt8qXlL9ggE20HzzXelNtdrhH8jpopH1hviXjjOogergBqNHpa96NfqbjPJEVtgjEkowpftdn2XAdFeTAMBwGCoAAeiQoxfW1KgHF4JxuAEKBGigd8oCYd44HNPCFBcV16Edcwf3iP9GGAjlSSZAkIL2RB1BkZhYPgxCULQlZqCwnC8IIoiSLI74Byo4AaMYIA)

Comment: Ya I had a type that just had unions of all my data types to start but it felt tedious because there are a lot more of them than is shown in the example and I also wanted just the type passed to the `on` function to be inferred and not a bunch of unions. I guess I incorrectly assumed that typescript would just use the type that is passed in when adding the listener `on<FileStartData>('file:start', onStart)` and then it would use `FileStartData` as the type for the function args but apparently that is not the case.

Comment: @user3331344 Then why not having a new specific type which is the union of all possible types and use that?